# Create Callback in DLL to use in MSVC Windows Forms

Tags: c++, winforms, dll

I wrote a dll( using MINGW and Codeblocks ) that should do the "background work" of my app.
I have an interface build in Microsoft Visual C++ 2015.

Is posible to control some TextBoxes, or Buttons( enable/disable ) or ProgressBars, or opening a new Form from the DLL ?

Any code snippet would be really apreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to create a DLL inside DLL, and shift properties to DLL.

Comment: i really don t understand what you said